# What is the idiomatic way of writing man pages for Rust CLI tools?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

CLI apps on Unix-like OSes generally provide man pages for reference. I have not yet seen any good guide on how to do this in the Rust ecosystem - what is the idiomatic way of doing this?

I am aware of the Cargo [build scripts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) feature, is this the way it is generally done? If yes, how would it generate man pages and how would it handle man installation on different OSes?

Comment: I believe following the [CLI working group](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/cli-wg/) will be most fruitful. They have a specific issue for [documentation of CLI apps](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/cli-wg/issues/23), which includes man pages.

Comment: Thanks for the links! After reading the documentation issue it seems man pages are an issue that has not been solved yet. I see ripgrep has a [working approach](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/master/build.rs#L71). I'll have a look into that.

Comment: The key insight to ripgrep's approach was to define a light abstraction over clap that stores the state of each clap arg, which can then be reused to build the tedious parts of a man page pretty easily. This abstraction layer could be avoided if clap grew an API to query its arguments. (But that is a fairly sizable change to clap, and solving the specific case of ripgrep is much easier than the fully general case.)

Answer (score 3):

The current best approach I am aware of is to use the [man](https://github.com/rust-cli/man) crate.  It is still a work in progress, and adding better support for man-page generation is an area that the CLI Working Group is actively working on.

As described in more detail in the README, `man` lets generate man pages from syntax like:

```
use man::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let page = Manual::new("basic")
        .about("A basic example")
        .author(Author::new("Alice Person").email("alice@person.com"))
        .author(Author::new("Bob Human").email("bob@human.com"))
        .flag(
            Flag::new()
                .short("-d")
                .long("--debug")
                .help("Enable debug mode"),
        )
        .flag(
            Flag::new()
                .short("-v")
                .long("--verbose")
                .help("Enable verbose mode"),
        )
        .option(
            Opt::new("output")
                .short("-o")
                .long("--output")
                .help("The file path to write output to"),
        )
        .example(
            Example::new()
                .text("run basic in debug mode")
                .command("basic -d")
                .output("Debug Mode: basic will print errors to the console")
            )
        .custom(
            Section::new("usage note")
                .paragraph("This program will overwrite any file currently stored at the output path")
        )
        .render();

    println!("{}", page);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At time of writing, there isn't a clear winner for generating man pages. The most common approaches in the ecosystem seem to be:

1. Write the man page directly, using troff syntax. Rust itself uses this approach, for example [`cargo-login.1`](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/3a77350b776f1132a27b07bf8d8f1be99b2edd10/src/etc/man/cargo-login.1) is used for `man cargo-login`.

   (If you don't like troff syntax, you can use helper libraries like [roff-rs](https://github.com/rust-cli/roff-rs) to generate troff.)
2. Derive a basic man page from the `--help` output of your binary using [`help2man`](https://www.gnu.org/software/help2man/). This is the approach used by [`xh`](https://github.com/ducaale/xh/blob/8e90649a535e82c07b0ec380f7e93d019236c890/generate.sh#L6).
3. Use [`clap_mangen`](https://crates.io/crates/clap_mangen) to generate a man page from a clap command at build time.